# inner Class Access EJB

Tags: java, ejb, inner-classes, wildfly

I would like to access a injected object from an inner class.
The strange thing is, that this works sometimes.
But sometimes I got an invocation exception:
org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: JBAS014559: Invocation cannot proceed as component is shutting down

I am using Wildfly 8.0 and 8.1.

```
@LocalBean
@Stateful
public class Outer {

@EJB AccessStateful accessStateful;
String s = "foo";

public void start(){
    Inner i = this.new Inner();
    i.doSomething;
}
public class Inner {
    public doSomething(){
        doPrivate();
    }
    private doPrivate(){
        Outer.this.accessStateful.accessMethode(s);
    }   
}
}

@LocalBean
@Stateful
public class AccessStateful{

public void accessMethode(String s){
    // do something here
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you're getting, it seems that this happens since you're trying to access the Outer class member while/after it is being destroyed.

Try to schedule the call to do whatever you want it to do, while the Outer EJB is still alive (using the EJB life-cycle annotations).